# A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Headers' property of type 'MiniListView'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

Here My Code,

```
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,43,43,0">
        <mine:MiniListView x:Name="Mini" Width="300" Headers="{Binding MyHeaders}"></mine:MiniListView>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" FontSize="10" Content="Add Row" Width="70" Height="20" />
    </StackPanel>
```

**Behind the Code:**

```
    public Dictionary<string, string> MyHeaders
    {
        get
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dic.Add("NAME", "BRANCH"); dic.Add("BANKNAME", "Percentage");
            return dic;
        }
    }
```

**Custom Class of mine:ministView**

```
public class MiniListView : ListView
{
   public static DependencyProperty HeadersProperty;
   public Dictionary<string, string> Headers
   {
      get { return (Dictionary<string, string>)base.GetValue(HeadersProperty); }
      set { base.SetValue(HeadersProperty, value); }
   }
   public MiniListView()
    {
        HeadersProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Headers", typeof(Dictionary<string, string>), typeof(MyListView));
        this.View = MyGrid();
    }
}
```

Here i'm trying to bindminlistivew HEADER'S PROPERTY WITH MyHeaders, getting this error

> *A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Headers' property of type 'MiniListView'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of
>   a DependencyObject.*

please tell me what's wrong  in my code.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Owner type` in dependency property registration is incorrect. It should be `MiniListView` and not `MyListView`

```
HeadersProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Headers",
                   typeof(Dictionary<string, string>), typeof(MiniListView));
```

Comment: Thank you, but again raised another error "A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Value' property of type 'DictionaryEntry'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject."

Comment: `Value` binding is not posted in question and that's altogether seperate question, not related to this. Error is self explanatory you can bind to only DP's. In `Headers` case you pass wrong owner type that's why DP is not found on `MiniListView`. Check for `Value` DP as well if it's registered properly.

Comment: Moreover it is very important *not* to call Register in the MiniListView instance constructor, but (because it is supposed to be done only once) in the class constructor. Or simply directly in the declaration of the static member: `public static readonly DependencyProperty HeadersProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(...);`.